# Загрузка файла из Oracle BIEE с помощью Python

Tags: python

Нет прямого доступа к БД, но есть доступ к Oracle BIEE. Сформированы ссылки на загрузку файлов (как на интерфейс, так и прямой пост запрос, который в ответ отдает xlsx), но в хроме я получаю загрузку, а в питоне при полном повторении запроса через reqests - b'' (пустой бинарник?).
Есть ли решения на Requests или Selenium для получения файла. Любое, как сохранение в директорию, так и сохранение данных в переменную (мне нужно распарсить данные из xlsx)
Ссылкой поделиться не могу.

[image: Интерфейс приложения при переходе по ссылке для загрузки]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос загрузкой файла из селениума, и обычным парсингом файлов. Крайне неэффективное решение, но работает